# Oops, no RSA or DSA server certificate found for 'server.host.name:0'?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I'm setting up a new web server that hosts a dozen virtual hosts on Ubuntu 12.4 using Apache 2.2.22 with one config file per site.  I created all the configuration files all at once and ran `a2ensite *` to enable them all at once.  When I reloaded the configuration it failed and after restarting apache I found the following error message in my error.log:

Oops, no RSA or DSA server certificate found for 'server.host.name:0'?!

Most of the results for this error message are years old that don't fix the problem or are bugs that have been fixed https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31709

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem ended up being in a *different* configuration file than the host that was listed in the error.  It was due to the fact that there were duplicate ServerName values in two of the files.  I fixed the wrong one and it started back up (bye bye that half an hour) :-) .

To troubleshoot this I disabled all the sites and then enabled a couple at a time until I ran into the problem again.

Answer (score 58):

From:
http://www.clearchain.com/blog/posts/solving-the-apache-ssl-error-oops-no-rsa-or-dsa-server-certificate-found-for-www-somedomain-com0

Summary: This error may also occur if you forget the following line in your `VirtualHost` section:

```
SSLEngine on
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also receive this error if you are using a cert with multiple subject alternate names, but the `ServerName` directive does not match the CN or SAN value(s) of the certificate. IT is often the case where a developer wants a development version of the same production site, but there is no real certificate for the development site.

Example websites:
webserver.example.com
webserver-dev.example.com

Certificate:
CN = primaryserver.example.com
SANs = webserver.example.com, puppies.example.com, kittens.example.com

The following configuration will cause this error:
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webserver.example.com-ssl.conf
`<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName webserver.example.com
...`
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webserver-dev.example.com-ssl.conf
`<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName webserver-dev.example.com
...`

The following configuration resolves this issue:
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webserver.example.com-ssl.conf
`<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName webserver.example.com
...`
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webserver.example.com-ssl.conf
`<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost webserver-dev.example.com:443>
        ServerName webserver.example.com
...`

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I just ran into this issue again, under a different guise.

If you are using wildcard SSL certificates, ensure that the VirtualHost entry for the domain (domain.com) is listed before anything else (foo.domain.com, bar.domain.com, etc).

I tried the one-at-a-time config thing, and everything else ran fine until I added the this one file back in.

Then I twigged on that the *config filename* was lower alphabetically than the config file with the "primary domain definition".  Changed the symlink so that it was placed after the main def and everything worked like a charm.

Example fail listing order:

```
foo.domain.conf
prim.domain.conf
something.domain.conf
```

Working example listing:

```
prim.domain.conf
something.domain.conf
zfoo.domain.conf
```

HTH someone else :)